# ¿Por qué mi procedimiento almacenado actualiza todos los registros en mi tabla MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
DELIMITER @@
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Actualizar_Cliente(
 IN Idcliente INT,
 IN Doccliente VARCHAR(11), 
 IN Nombre VARCHAR(45), 
 IN Apellido VARCHAR(45), 
 IN Direccion VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
 UPDATE cliente SET
  doccliente=Doccliente,
  nombre=Nombre,
  apellido=Apellido,
  direccion=Direccion
 WHERE idcliente=Idcliente;
END @@ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Porque `idcliente = idcliente` es siempre verdadero (a menos que idcliente sea `NULL`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renombra los parámetros de entrada, por ejemplo:

```
DELIMITER @@
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Actualizar_Cliente(
 IN var_Idcliente INT,
 IN var_Doccliente VARCHAR(11), 
 IN var_Nombre VARCHAR(45), 
 IN var_Apellido VARCHAR(45), 
 IN var_Direccion VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
 UPDATE cliente SET
  doccliente=var_Doccliente,
  nombre=var_Nombre,
  apellido=var_Apellido,
  direccion=var_Direccion
 WHERE idcliente=var_Idcliente;
END @@ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Las versiones para windows de MySql por lo general no diferencian entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, por esa razón, como dijo @lamak tu condición `idcliente=Idcliente` siempre es verdadera y cambia todos los registros de la tabla